# no input method in fcitx on debian

Tags: debian

I tried reinstall fcitx-googlepinyin on debian with "sudo apt-get remove fcitx-googlepinyin"&&"sudo apt-get install fcitx-googlepinyin",but it appears to be "no input method" in fcitx config, it worked well yesterday .anyone who can help me ?

Answer (score 4):

Run `fcitx-diagnose`.
Plus I don't think this is the right place to ask these questions. We have googlegroup and issue trackers.